# Only return one value for name, SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a SQL query that returns stuff in this order

- name of who has 99781 key if value is positive (it will be max 1)
- name of who has 99780 key if value is positive (it can be max 2)
- name of who has 99777 key in order of value (the rest until the limit of 5 from select)

(Those limits on 99781 and 99780 key it's already by the system, doesn't have to limit on show)

I was using:

```
SELECT t2.name as name, t1.key as keyy, t1.value as valuee 
FROM player_storage t1 INNER JOIN players t2 on t2.id = t1.player_id 
WHERE t1.value > 0 AND t1.key IN (99781,99780,99777) 
ORDER BY keyy+0 DESC, valuee+0 DESC LIMIT 5
```

Output:

| name | keyy | valuee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Max | 99781 | 1 |
| Carl | 99780 | 1 |
| Max | 99777 | 402 |
| Carl | 99777 | 395 |
| Paul | 99777 | 370 |

But if name Max have 99781 as 1, and 99777 key as 400.
I don't want to return his 99777 key, since he already have 99781 key.
Same with Carl (99780 key).

The result I want:

| name | keyy | valuee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Max | 99781 | 1 |
| Carl | 99780 | 1 |
| Paul | 99777 | 370 |
| Mike | 99777 | 320 |
| John | 99777 | 55 |

A user here on Stack Overflow, helped me get to this:

```
SELECT t2.name as name, t1.key as keyy, t1.value as valuee 
FROM player_storage t1 INNER JOIN players t2 on t2.id = t1.player_id 
WHERE t1.value > 0 
AND
(
    t1.key IN (99781, 99780)
    OR
    (
        t1.key IN (99777)
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 5 FROM player_storage tx
            WHERE tx.player_id = t1.player_id
            AND tx.key > t1.key
        )
    )
)
ORDER BY keyy+0 DESC, valuee+0 DESC LIMIT 5
```

But it's getting only 1 name with 99777 key, even if there are more to show.
It's not going to limit 5, result of this:

| name | keyy | valuee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Max | 99781 | 1 |
| Carl | 99780 | 1 |
| Paul | 99777 | 370 |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want one row per name, with the rows ordered by `key` in descending order.  That would be:

```
select ps.*
from (select p.name as name, ps.key as key, p.value as value
             row_number() over (partition by name order by key desc) as seqnum
      from player_storage ps join
           players p
           on p.id = ps.player_id 
      where ps.key in (99781, 99780, 99777)
     ) ps
where seqnum = 1;
```

All your values are positive numbers, so I don't understand why there is a condition on positive values.  Of course, you can add `and value > 0` to the subquery to enforce this.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's giving me syntax error. I can't see the table name on your query also.

Comment: @YuriAniceto . . . I adjusted the answer based on the code in your question.

Comment: I'm trying to run it on phpmyadmin database to test, got this: #1064 - You have a syntax error on your SQL next to 'key, p.value as value
             row_number() over (partition by name orde...' on line 2

Comment: @YuriAniceto . . . Adjust the column names.  `key` is a SQL keyword and is inappropriate for a column name.  I just kept the names from your sample code.

Comment: i'm sorry, the column name needs to be key since it's what the system uses. The codes on the post are working, but i can't make yours work, I'm not good with sql.

Comment: don't give up on me, please.

Comment: @YuriAniceto . . . You should set up a DB/SQL Fiddle of some sort.